# Unidentified issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a html file with a registration form, and want the data saved in a mysql database.

I have a `login.php` file to connect to the mysql database that looks like this:

```
<?php 
$db_hostname = 'localhost'; 
$db_database = 'tester'; 
$db_username = 'p2';
$db_password = 'adgangskode';
?>
```

The other php file is called `proces_input.php` and look like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$connection = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

if(!$connection) {
    die("Cant connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$selected_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, $db_database);

if(!$selected_db){
    die("Couldnt decide database: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}    
$fornavn = $_POST['fornavn'];
$efternavn = $_POST['efternavn'];
$adresse = $_POST['adresse'];
$postnummer = $_POST['postnummer'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$telefonnummer = $_POST['telefonnummer'];
$fdag = $_POST['fdag'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$insert_query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$fornavn', '$efternavn',
'$adresse', '$postnummer', '$city', '$telefonnummer', '$fdag', '$password',
'$email')";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $insert_query);
if(!$result){ 
die ("Acces to database denied: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

When I fill out the form and submit the data i get the error:

> "Acces to database denied".

To solve the problem I have tried to run the following code in mysql:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON tester.* TO p2@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'adgangskode';
```

This solution didn't seem to work out, so I am looking for someone who hopefully can give me an answer to the problem.

Comment: Missing `$` at `insert_query`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this code:

```
insert_query = "INSERT INTO users VALUE ('$fornavn', '$efternavn',
'$adresse', '$postnummer', '$city', '$telefonnummer', '$fdag', '$password',
'$email')";
```

with this code:

```
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$fornavn', '$efternavn',
'$adresse', '$postnummer', '$city', '$telefonnummer', '$fdag', '$password',
'$email')";
```

You seem to have miss-spelled `VALUE` when it should be `VALUES`.

Also, you forgot to include `$` before `insert_query`

Let me know if it works now!

Comment: The difference between the two lines is the word "VALUE" and "VALUES".

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu what's wrong with it? The dude miss-spelled his sql statement

Comment: Sorry I did not notice that the spelling :(

Comment: oh i thought in a wrong way. sorry. i thought you are angry on me. Now remove all these comments because they are not related to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The missing $ before insert_query, was only in this post. It´s actually in my php code, but somehow I deleted it when copied it in this thread. I have also tried to change VALUE to VALUES without no result. The syntax in my PHP file seems to be allright, but I don't know why it can't connect to the mysql database.

Comment: @Elfernovich well it should be something in the SQL statement because that is where your code is failing. I actually think I know why... you are only supposed to put apostrophes ('') for string variables like varchar(255)..., check if you placed (') around numbers. $telefonnummer is probably a number hahah. Let me know if that solves the problem!

Comment: It finally worked. Thank you a lot for the quick respons.
In my HTML-form I have a checkbox for a newsletter: 
<label>Tilmeld nyhedsbrev: 
        <input type="checkbox" value='1' id="nyhedsbrev" name="nyhedsbrev"></label>

How do I add a row in the mysql table that can handle an input from a checkbox? It could be "1", like I have set the value above.

Comment: @Elfernovich! No problem, nema sta, kad god tebe treba! Oh and if my answer was the on that worked for you, please accept it as the answer (green check mark) so that future users know it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1):

To give privileges:

GRANT ALL ON database TO username@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

Please find the link for more details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

your `insert_query` must be `$insert_query`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried the following command to give the user privileges:
GRANT ALL ON tester TO p2@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'adgangskode';
But it didnt help. The $insert_query was already in my PHP file, but was somehow deleted when I copied the text in here.

Comment: Try this:    GRANT ALL  ON tester.* TO 'p2'@'localhost' ;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;